# How do I get a Metal texture ID to render to it with Ogre?

Tags: ios, metal

I looked in the documentation, but I don't know how to get the texture ID.

```
void* texPtr = SixDegreesSDK_GetBackgroundTexture();
            if (texPtr != nil) {
                id<MTLTexture> mtlTexture = (__bridge id<MTLTexture>)texPtr;

                id<MTLDevice> device = [mtlTexture device];
                // !!! Not fond of creating a new command queue for every texture
                id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];
                id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
                id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];

                NSUInteger textureWidth = mtlTexture.width;
                NSUInteger textureHeight = mtlTexture.height;
                NSUInteger rowbytes = mtlTexture.bufferBytesPerRow;
                MTLPixelFormat  pixFormat = mtlTexture.pixelFormat;
                CVPixelBufferRef _CVPixelBuffer = NULL;
                NSDictionary* cvBufferProperties = @{
                                                     (__bridge NSString*)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                                                     (__bridge NSString*)kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                                                     };
                CVReturn cvret = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                     textureWidth, textureHeight,
                                                     kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA,
                                                     (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)cvBufferProperties,
                                                     &_CVPixelBuffer);
                const IOSurfaceRef surface  = CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface(_CVPixelBuffer);             // available in ios11 sdk, ios4 runtime

                MTLTextureDescriptor* textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:pixFormat
                                                                                                             width:textureWidth
                                                                                                            height:textureHeight
                                                                                                         mipmapped:NO];
                id<MTLTexture> metalTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor
                                                                          ioSurface:surface
                                                                              plane:0];

                MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight);

                [blitEncoder copyFromTexture:mtlTexture
                                 sourceSlice:0
                                 sourceLevel:0
                                sourceOrigin:region.origin
                                  sourceSize:region.size
                                   toTexture:metalTexture
                            destinationSlice:0
                            destinationLevel:0
                           destinationOrigin:region.origin];

                [blitEncoder endEncoding];
                [commandBuffer commit];
                [self.mEAGLContext texImageIOSurface:surface target:GL_TEXTURE_2D internalFormat:GL_RGBA width:textureWidth height:textureHeight format:GL_RGBA type:GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE plane:0];
```

Comment: Why do you think there's a texture ID? If you had one, what would you do with it?

Comment: I'm sharing it with Ogre texture, that I need the texture ID and let ogre renders it..

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. You should also not crosspost the same question to different Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I edited to include the additional detail. What's that code sample doing? Isn't it exactly what you're looking for? (The value seems to be of type `id<MTLTexture>`.)

Comment: @Anko I don't know how to call the blit command, and don't understand why I need to create an IOSurface for that purpose.. I already have the texture MTL from the SDK.. so why I need to create an IOSurface for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ogre does not support Metal at this time. `MTLTexture` does not have any concept of a texture ID. If one library is returning a `MTLTexture` and the other expects an OpenGL texture ID, you'll need to copy the `MTLTexture` into an OpenGL texture created using `IOSurface`s.

The [documentation on `IOSurfaces`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface/iosurface?language=objc) is a bit slim, unfortunately. Once you have an `IOSurface`, you can blit the `MTLTexture` into it using a [`MTLBlitCommandEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder?language=objc). You can then retrieve an OpenGL texture from the `IOSurface` via [`CGLTexImageIOSurface2D()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077544/draw-an-iosurface-to-an-opengl-context).

It might look something like this (not actually compiled, probably needs cleaning up):

```
NSDictionary* properties = @{ 
    IOSurfacePropertyKeyWidth : [NSNumber numberWithInt:textureWidth],
    IOSurfacePropertyKeyHeight : [NSNumber numberWithInt:textureHeight],
    IOSurfacePropertyKeyRowBytes : [NSNumber numberWithInt:rowbytes],
    IOSurfacePropertyKeyPixelFormat : [NSNumber numberWithInt:pixFormat],
    // ... etc. with any other relevant properties
};
IOSurface* ioSurface = [[IOSurface alloc] initWithProperties:properties];
```

Next you can get a `MTLTexture` from the `IOSurface` by doing this:

```
MTLTextureDescriptor* textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:pixFormat
                                                                                             width:textureWidth
                                                                                            height:textureHeight
                                                                                         mipmapped:NO];
id<MTLTexture> metalTexture = [metalDevice newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor
                                                          ioSurface:ioSurface
                                                              plane:0];
```

Now, I've never personally used a `MTLBlitEncoder`, so I don't know the gory details, but it looks like once you've created one, you can call [`-[MTLBlitCommandEncoder copyFromTexture:sourceSlice:sourceLevel:sourceOrigin:sourceSize:toTexture:destinationSlice:destinationLevel:destinationOrigin:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400754-copyfromtexture?language=objc). I believe once that blit command has been completed, the `IOSurface` will contain the texture data. Apple has some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/resource_objects/argument_buffers_with_arrays_and_resource_heaps) showing how to use them.

From there you can do:

```
GLint glTextureID = CGTexImageIOSurface2D(glContext, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_RGBA, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_BRGA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, ioSurface, 0);
```

(That assumes you want an 8-bit per channel RGBA texture and that the `MTLTexture` was in that format.)

[Here's some additional sample code for sharing between Metal and OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mixing_metal_and_opengl_rendering_in_a_view).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86835/discussion-between-andre-ahmed-and-user1118321).